# How to create a selector with a vector assets over a circle?

Tags: android, xml

I want to implement a toggle button that can pass from "start" to "pause" with the following design:

[image]

I put a `ToggleButton`, and I tried to use the following selector, but it does not work. In fact, only the circled background is displayed, but not the vector images (xml files) of the play and pause icons...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_pause_black_24dp">
        </item>

        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <layer-list>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_black_24dp">
        </item>

        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must be because of the order, try it this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_pause_black_24dp">
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_black_24dp">
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

Comment: Glad to be of help ;)